# How to change line height of a pdf

Tags: pdf, adobe-acrobat

This `.pdf` has a line height bigger than the font size so it's difficult to select the text and the highlights overflow on the other lines.

How can I change the line height so that it fit the font size?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I could solve this by printing the `.pdf` (File/Print then choose Adobe PDF as the printer and keep normal settings ). 
If printing doesn't work, you can export as a `Word Document` (in `File>Save As`), and then open this file in MS Word and select `Save as` and set the format to `.pdf`.

If there are highlights in the original`.pdf`, printing will flatten them so they can't be removed (they are part of the background).

[image]

I try to bypass this by making a copy of the `.pdf`, removing all the highlights in the copy, printing the copy and finally importing the highlights but it doesn't works: the imported highlights aren't added to the correct positions (the highlight on Lorem ipsum dolor was added manually in the printed .pdf)

[image]

### So I don't have any solution for the moment if I have many highlights

How to import the highlights:
[image]

Comment: Can you copy the text and paste it, for example, in Word or Photoshop? Because in this case you could increase the space between the lines (leading) and save again as PDF.

Comment: Yes I can, but printing it is way easier